# Doing a loop only 5 times

Tags: bash, shell, unix, loops

I want to do a loop `(for file in *)` only 5 times (so it's not a real loop anymore but however) is there anyway to do this?

Comment: In what way does limiting a loop to 5 iterations render it "not a real loop"?

Comment: There is the `seq` command also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the files in an array, then slice the array.

```
$ files=(*)
$ for file in "${files[@]::5}" ; do echo "$file" ; done
あいうえお
0000000000-11-005978.txt
0000000000-11-020832.txt
1
,123
```

Answer (score 1):

This will only look at the first five items in the directory:

```
for file in $(ls | head -5)
```

As Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams points-out, this only works if your filenames don't contain any whitespace. (They likely won't, but something to keep in mind.)

Comment: Unless one of them has whitespace in the filename.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Hmm, that's pretty rare, though you are correct.

Comment: @chrisaycock: Whitespace in file names it not really rare. `for file in "$(ls -1 | head -5)"; do echo "$file"; done` does what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @Dennis: that doesn't work, because the double-quotes make it treat all 5 filenames (and the newlines between them) as a single value for $file.  Replace the echo command with `echo "file='$file'"` and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the variable i is undefined or 0 when you enter the loop and is not used in the loop, just add the line:

```
test $((++i)) -ge 5 && break
```

in the loop body.  The loop will break out during the 5th iteration, so if you put the line at the end of the loop body, your commands will execute 5 times.  If your shell supports it, you can also use the less portable

```
((++i >= 5)) && break
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another solution, which only uses bash and no external tools:

```
let COUNT=0
for FILENAME in *
do
    echo do something to $FILENAME
    let COUNT=COUNT+1
    if (( $COUNT == "5" )); then
        break
    fi
done
```